# How can I import salesforce marketing cloud in ios (react native)

Tags: react-native, salesforce-marketing-cloud

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

How can I import salesforce marketing cloud in ios

After npm install and pod install, when I put the below code in AppDelegate.m

```
MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder *mcsdkBuilder = [MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder new];
[mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setApplicationId:@"{MC_APP_ID}"];
[mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setAccessToken:@"{MC_ACCESS_TOKEN}"];
[mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setAnalyticsEnabled:@(YES)];
[mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setMarketingCloudServerUrl:@"{MC_APP_SERVER_URL}"];

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success =
    [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_configureWithDictionary:[mcsdkBuilder sfmc_build]
                                                               error:&error];
```

It show some error regarding Use of undeclared identifier.
Like Use of undeclared identifier 'mcsdkBuilder'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Documentation from Salesforce is incomplete, you need to add these two imports:

```
#import <MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK.h>
#import <MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder.h>
```